# NogotoFail Android

Tags: android, ssl, network-security, nogotofail

Nogotofail was recently released by Google and I want to use it to test an Android App I created that connects to a C# server.

I read through the documentation and I'm confused on how to use it. I have ubuntu running as a virtualbox machine on my laptop. I have the two android apps that come with Nogotofail installed on my device. I believe I followed the steps but I'm not getting any results. has anybody used this to test and Android app???

This is what the documentation says on git regarding testing Android:

```
    For testing Android devices we have included our Android client 
ready to be imported into Eclipse. You will have to build the app and install it on your test device.

    For testing you can use the access point nogotofail setups or 
on devices >=JB you can use the OpenVPN setup and a third party VPN application to route your traffic
```

My app connects to my server on my localhost:443 and sends a message and receives a response from the server. Where do I point the nogotofail.mitm that runs on ubuntu? Where do I point the nogotofail android app where it says host address?

Nogotofail just came out in November 2014 so there isn't much out there in terms of tutorials...not even on stack..
Any help would be appreciated